# Arduino Nano stuck on uploading

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I recently bought an Arduino Nano ( a clone actually), I installed the CH340G drivers for it and got it working perfectly fine... Played around with it for a while and then kept it aside...

Now after sometime I get time to play with it again, I was actually trying to power it with my 11.1V 2200mAh 8C LiPo battery. So I plug the JST connector to the Vin and GND pin and the LED doesn't light up. I noticed that I had plugged it in the wrong way and I immediately unplugged it. Next I make another attempt and this time I plugged the pins entirely somewhere else, again I disconnect quickly. The third time I connect it properly and the power LED lights up (phew...)

Now I move on to my computer to program it but the Arduino IDE is stuck at uploading. It was working fine before, when I hit upload, the RX LED glows *VERY* dimly and the board just stays like that. Only the power LED glows up, not even the LED on pin 13 glows up.
Uploading to a UNO works perfectly fine.

This is the error I get after a while-

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x7d

Did I burn my board? Or is it just a bootloader issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I plug the JST connector to the Vin and GND pin and the LED doesn't light up. I noticed that I had plugged it in the wrong way and I immediately unplugged it. Next I make another attempt and this time I plugged the pins entirely somewhere else, again I disconnect quickly. The third time I connect it properly and the power LED lights up (phew...)

Unfortunately Vin on an [Arduino Nano](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf) does not have a reverse polarity protection diode such as the [Arduino Uno PWRin](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf)

> Did I burn my board?

Very probable. For more details please see "[10 Ways to Destroy an Arduino](http://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/)".

Cheers!

Comment: that's not at all good... Now I'm gonna have to run around with a UNO strapped to my wrist instead of the Nano

Comment: It's unfortunate and I guess not the answer you where looking for. Please leave the question open if you need further answers or mark as answered.

Comment: I guess you've already answered the main point of the question so.. I'll mark it as answered.